# Internal storage insufficient storage problem

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Lenovo Android phone with 8GB of space, but I can't download, upgrade or even store more apps. It tells me that I have insufficient STORAGE

Comment: Might want to start looking here... http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info

Comment: And if the above link doesn't answer your question, go to the "votes" tab from that same page to find many working solutions.

Comment: Simply, just uninstall unused apps, install Clean Master app. Better if you root and learn to use Link2SD.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, insert an SD card and move apps to it.

In case you have android marshmallow, you can insert the SD card and set it as your internal storage.

You can also try to clear the cache of your device.

If your device is old enough, you could think about rooting it and uninstalling bloatware apps. You can remove system app without root (with adb), but it works shit.